# NoClassDefFoundError for StartCalculatorActivity class

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, google-glass

I'm new to Android/Glass development. I am trying to make a calculator which is voice controlled. The runtime crash occurs due to this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/glass/widget/CardBuilder;
```

The StartCalculatorActivity class is :

```
public class StartCalculatorActivity extends Activity {


    private CardScrollView mCardScroller;
    CardBuilder card;
    private View mView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        card = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT);
        mView = buildView();

        mCardScroller = new CardScrollView(this);
        mCardScroller.setAdapter(new CardScrollAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return mView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return mView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getPosition(Object item) {
                if (mView.equals(item)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION;
            }
        });
        // Handle the TAP event.
        mCardScroller.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Plays disallowed sound to indicate that TAP actions are not supported.
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.playSoundEffect(Sounds.DISALLOWED);
            }
        });
        setContentView(mCardScroller);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCardScroller.activate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mCardScroller.deactivate();
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a Glass styled "Hello World!" view using the {@link CardBuilder} class.
     /*/
    private View buildView() {


        card.setText(R.string.hello_world);
        return card.getView();
    }

}
```

I added JAR files to my buildpath by making a new directory and copy -pasting the JARs into it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: that error is saying that the program can't find the jar during RUNTIME. So, check your runtime classpath

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060105/google-glass-returning-noclassdeffounderror-for-glass-widget-cardbuilder

Comment: I had a look at that question, however I am not using "Card", instead using "CardBuilder" already. @YingYang

Comment: I went to project->right-clicked on app->clicked on Open Module Settings->Dependencies. The library I had added was present there with Scope " Compile". @AsierAranbarri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run an application which requires google glass, you will first have to download glass on your android phone after which you will be able to use such an app.

[Checkout this link](https://pathofacoder.com/2013/07/19/installing-google-glass-in-an-android-phone/)